# How do I solve this: "Step forward and backward problem"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

### The Problem Statement:

Sanjay is addicted to alcohol. Every night he drinks 4 bottles of vodka. He is going to his home. At first, he takes a step forward (which is 5m) but beacuse he is drunk, after his each step in forward direction, his body gets imbalanced and he takes a step backward (which is 3m).

Each step takes 1 min to complete. The distance from the bar to home is n metres. Calculate the time taken by him to reach his home.

### Input Format:

single line containing one integer n.

### Constraints:

```
0 <= n < 10^18
```

### Output Format

single integer describing the time taken by him to reach home.

```
from math import *
n = int(input())
x = 0
m = 0
n = n % 1000000007
n = n % 1000000007
while  x < n:
    x += 5
    m += 1
    if x >= n:
        break
    x -= 3
    m += 1
print(m)
```

But the time limit is exceeding in the last test case i.e. for n = 10^18 like numbers

> Sample Input 0
>
> 11
>
> Sample Output 0
>
> 7

Comment: Please can you clarify what the problem is "the time limit is exceeding in the last test case!" doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @SimonN Probably a codewars / hackerrank problem or similar

Comment: You can solve this in `O(1)` time... **Hint:** the solution is approximately `n / ((5-2) / 2)`.

Comment: I'd imagine the proper solution doesn't involve looping at all.

Comment: This is more of a simple math problem than a programming one. ¯\\\_(ツ)\_/¯

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I tried (((n-5)/2)*2)+1 but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide additional explanation as to why you think yours is the correct solution?

Comment: With math problems it's helpful to create a table of the first 5-10 inputs/outputs to try to find a pattern. The algorithm may come easily after you've found a pattern as you may be able to remove extraneous information.

Answer (score 0):

The time taken is simply n/2 * 2
He advances 2 meters each "cycle" 5 forward 3 back 
So we see how many "cycles" go into n (n / 2m) this will result
In the number of "cycles" taken to reach his house
Then we simply multiply by the amount of time taken per cycle (2 minutes)
to get the total time taken (t = n/2 * 2).

Comment: No: if the 5 meter step makes it home, that counts. It's approximately n/2, but not exactly.

Comment: No, if that were the case, then for 11 metres, it would take him 11 minutes, and not 7 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing the problem. Let `time_taken(dist)` be the function that tells us how long it takes to get home. Then the following hold:

```
time_taken(1)  ==  1
time_taken(2)  ==  1
time_taken(3)  ==  1
time_taken(4)  ==  1
time_taken(5)  ==  1

time_taken(6)  ==  1 * 2 + time_taken(4)    (since 5-3 = 2)
               ==  1 * 2 + 1

time_taken(7)  ==  1 * 2 + time_taken(5)
               ==  1 * 2 + 1

time_taken(11) ==  1 * 2 + time_taken(9)
               ==  2 * 2 + time_taken(7)
               ==  3 * 2 + time_taken(5)
               ==  3 * 2 + 1

time_taken(26) ==  1 * 2 + time_taken(24)
               ==  2 * 2 + time_taken(22)
               ==  ...
               ==  11 * 2 + time_taken(4)
               ==  11 * 2 + 1

if n > 5:
time_taken(n)  ==  1 * 2 + time_taken(n - 2)
               ==  2 * 2 + time_taken(n - 4)
               ==  ...
               ==  (formula here) * 2 + time_taken(4 or 5)
```

Comment: Appreciate you're trying to gently guide the OP to solving the problem themselves but this question has drifted a long way from being on-topic. We're not doing anything with code, but instead going round the houses to tease out the solution to a very simple maths problem.